# Handlebars each/this

Tags: express-handlebars

I use the Handlebars template engine:

```
`{{#each classes}}
<div class="col_4">
    <h4>{{this.title}}</h4>
    <p>{{this.description}}</p>
    <a class="button" href="/classes/{{_id}}/details">View Class</a>
</div>
{{/each}}`
```

Why is it not possible to address title and description as individual fields of this?
If I use "this" like this:

```
{{#each classes}}
<div class="col_4">
    <h4>{{this}}</h4>
    <p>{{this}}</p>
    <a class="button" href="/classes/{{_id}}/details">View Class</a>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

all fields are displayed merged.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works with an earlier version:

```
{{#each classes }}
 <div class="col_4">
    <h4>{{title}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <a class="button" href="/classes/{{_id}}/details">View Class</a>
 </div>
{{/each}}
```